# Too many arguments for function call operator overload

Tags: c++, syntax, struct, functor

I'm attempting to overload the `() operator` to accept a `long`, that code is below.

```
struct print{
    void operator()(long x){
        printf("Number: %d\n",x);
    }
};
```

However when I write this:

```
print p();
long l = 10;
p(l);
```

The compiler yells at me saying "error : too many arguments in function call" on the line that corresponds to `p(l);`

Why isn't this working, did I overload the `() operator` correctly?

Comment: Is it possible to overload `()`?

Comment: yes you can overload the () it is called a functor or function object...heres a link to a youtube vid that gives a code example of a functor http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BQz0ZXMye4&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You hit the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Change `print p();` to `print p;`.

`print p()` is a declaration of a **function** named `p` which returns a print object.

Also, in C++, an empty parameter list means a function taking no arguments (same as `(void)`), which is why the compiler complains: " too many arguments in function call".

Comment: Jesse, you're good. Pun intended. :-D